# A Frobenius norm inequality for sum of rank one matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $u,w \in S^{n-1}$ and $v,z \in S^{m-1}$.  The goal is to show that
$$
\|u v^T - w z^T\|_F^2  \leq \|u-w\|_2^2 + \|v -z\|_2^2 
$$
Expanding both sides eventually simplifies to
$$
u^T w + v^T z - (u^T w)(v^T z) \leq 1.
$$
As this inequality is always true, the result is proved, but I'm looking for a more intuitive (or possibly geometric) proof.

Note: $\|A \|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm = $\sqrt{\sum_{ij} A_{ij}^2}$.

Comment: Is there a way to use Minkowski's inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different argument, which you might find more intuitive perhaps.
By the rotational invariance of the Frobenius and $2$-norms, we can assume $n=m=2,$ $v=w=(1,0),$ $u=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ and $z=(\cos\beta,\sin\beta)$ for some $\alpha,\beta.$ This gives

$$uv^T-wz^T=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha-\cos\beta&-\sin\beta\\
\sin\alpha&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

If $\cos\alpha\geq\cos\beta$ then $0\leq \cos\alpha-\cos\beta\leq 1-\cos\beta,$ so we can bound the sum of squares of the matrix entries by $(1-\cos\beta)^2+(\sin\beta)^2+(\sin\alpha)^2+(1-\cos\alpha)^2=\|v-z\|_2+\|u-w\|_2.$ The case $\cos\alpha\leq\cos\beta$ can be handled similarly.